# How to add additional options for export dropdown in a reportviewer

Tags: rdlc, reportviewer, export-to-csv

Do anyone have good ideas of how an additional option can be added to the existing export drop down menu in a report viewer?

Currently it has Excel, PDF and Word , and i want to add one more option that export the data to .csv format.

Thank you

Comment: I think this is all you get for 'local reports' with report viewer. You get more if you use reports hosted on an SSRS server. Is that an option? Alternatively you could replace the toolbar with your own controls, and programmatically work with the report to make your own export to CSV. Is that an option?

Comment: To expand on that, from the gotreportviewer website, Q: What are the limitations of ReportViewer control?
A: Unlike the Report Server the ReportViewer control does not connect to databases or execute queries. Also, in local mode the only export formats available are Excel, Word and PDF. (In remote mode all formats supported by the Report Server are available.) The ReportViewer control cannot be extended by adding custom renderers or custom report items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using local reports (as the tags on on this question suggests), you cannot add more options to the export dropdown, as this is a limitation of the ReportViewer control in this mode.